# Final 3 players on the table

Tags: all-in

Player A small blind of 10K Player B big blind of 20K Player C decided to say ALL IN Player A decided to call C Player B decided to say ALL IN Player A didn't know B said ALL IN Player C showed the cards, so Player A decided to show cards too. Player B showed the cards too. Player C won the least pot which was 219K then Player B said where is my chips from Player A? Player A said why my chips? Player B said I decided to go ALL IN. Player A was like what? U did say all in, I didn't know.

In this situation, what would u do??

Comment: Tournament or cash game, home game or casino?

Answer (score 1):

You don't just announce all in.  Some times your push all you chips and some times you can just place one chip.  Especially if there is only one person left the may fold so moving all your chips in and out is a lot of extra movement.  Some games have an all in token.

Confusing
A 10K
B 20K
C 73K all in
A 73K call
B ???
C show
A show

If B still has cards in front of him then he is in the hand.  C and A acted out of turn.

If B was all in then he should have chips in the pot.

This game sounds messed up.